# Getting null when trying to change datatype in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset C1.txt that has one column named features.All the rows are string and represent x and y, The coordinates of a two-dimensional point. I want to change the type to double but when I'm doing that by this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import(StructField,StringType,IntegerType,StructType,DoubleType) 
changedTypedf =df.withColumn("features", df["features"].cast(DoubleType()))
```

I receive null for all rows [(before changing datatype)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ2s6.png).

[image: after changing datatype]

I don't know what is the wrong,please help me solving this problem.
Thanks

Comment: you have space between value so how could you convert into the double. if you are using read CSV file then it would be great if you can use inferSchema option while reading  the file

Comment: Thanks for replying,yes you'r right.how can I change it to standard form?I have the .txt file.